# How can I tell where an OpenOffice Writer document extends beyond set margins?

Tags: pdf, openoffice-writer, publishing

I am using OpenOffice.org Writer to create a PDF, and have explicitly set margins of 1" all around. CreateSpace, which I am creating the PDF for, has rejected my PDF on the claim that it does not have at least a 1" inner boundary.

What can I do to my Writer or PDF files so that this doesn't happen? I've placed the main body in http://jonathanscorner.com/project/best/the_best_of_jonathans_corner_body.odt , http://jonathanscorner.com/project/best/the_best_of_jonathans_corner_body.pdf (also contains the header), and the header in http://jonathanscorner.com/project/best/the_best_of_jonathans_corner_head.odt and http://jonathanscorner.com/project/best/the_best_of_jonathans_corner_body.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem be related to the presumed paper dimensions?  A4 is narrower (but longer) than US Letter size and that could be a difficulty, for example.  CreateSpace has its own rules for PDFs that can be produced as print (and presumably digital forms as well).  Did you follow this ?: https://www.createspace.com/Products/Book/InteriorPDF.jsp

Check the CreateSpace rules for trim sizes.  The inner boundary is not the same as page margin.  I think you need to allow for the trim size.

Try converting one of the CreateSpace .doc boilerplate/template files to ODF (via OpenOffice) and seeing how to match all of the appropriate settings.